# How can I pass python variable in os.system

Tags: python, os.system

I am trying to pass the output of one `os.system()` to another `os.system()`.

However, I am getting no output.

```
user = os.system("whoami")
print (user)
box=os.system("docker ps -a --format \"{{.Names}}\" | grep user")
print (box)
```

Output:

```
xvision
256
```

Comment: In the docker call, the `user` is a string, not the variable.  Which is likely why `grep` isn’t finding `'user'`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple issues with the posted code:

1. The `user` in the `grep` command is a *string*, not the variable I believe you are intending to use.
2. The [return value](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system) from `os.system` is simply the exit status of the command; *not* the values which you are looking to retrieve.
3. If I'm not mistaken, docker will require elevated permissions to execute the a `ps` command. Perhaps your `visudo` is setup differently than mine, which allows the command - but something to be aware of.

Additionally, the first system call to get the username is unneeded, as the shell call can be used instead, as `grep $( whoami )`. However, if you are expecting a different username on the docker system, you can use an f-string as:

```
f'grep | {user}'
```

Instead, the `subprocess` library should be used here as you can retrieve the values from the subprocess call.

For example:

```
import subprocess

# Note: sudo might be optional in your case, depending on setup.
rtn = subprocess.Popen('sudo docker ps -a --format {{.Names}} | grep $( whoami )', 
                       shell=True, 
                       stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                       stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()

>>> rtn
(b'username', None)  # <-- tuple of (stdout, stderr)
```

Getting the username:

```
value = rtn[0].decode()

>>> value
'username'
```

---

A note on the `shell` call:

Some might argue that '`shell` should be avoided'. However, in this case I'm choosing to use it for the following reasons:

- To make the command string a bit easier to read for the OP.
- To (more easily) facilitate the pipe into `grep`.

Without the pipe into grep, the command *could* be split into a list of arguments; thus alleviating the need for the shell call.

Comment: In the question, the command does not use `sudo`, so is it an additional problem with the question or is it not required? If sudo is required, it may be worth to mention that the python script needs to be executed with sudo rights, too. Also, do we need `shell=True`? IMO both should be shortly discussed in the answer :-)

Comment: Good points, thank you.  Added some commentary regarding `sudo`. In my testing, the shell does need to be explicitly invoked, otherwise a `FileNotFoundError` is raised.

Comment: The docker daemon must always run as the root user, but I am here running the docker client as a user in the docker group so I don't need to add sudo to all the client commands.